# No line break with colored git branch in bash prompt

Tags: bash, bashrc, prompt

I added a function to my `.bashrc` to parse the git branch I'm currently working in and display it in my bash-prompt according to several tutorials on this topic.
My code snippet looks like this:

```
parse_git_branch() { 
   BRANCH=$(git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/')
   if [ "$BRANCH" != "" ]; then
      echo -e "[\e[1;31m⎇ $BRANCH\e[1;37m]"
   else
      echo "╼"
   fi
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1;37m\]┌[\[\033[1;32m\]\u\[\033[1;37m\]@\[\033[1;32m\]\H\[\033[1;37m\]] [\w]\n└$(parse_git_branch) \[\033[00m\]'

else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

This does as expected print the current git branch in red if there is one:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTThR.png)

However, if the command is really long, the line doesn't break anymore: 
[another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZI06.png)

The problem goes away if I don't use the `-e` flag for `echo` in `parse_git_branch`, but I need it to color the branch red.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

All the other solutions I found while googling this just print either the colored git branch or nothing, so they don't quite work for me since i want it to print the git branch if there is one *and if not* print that `╼`-character in white.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the color sequences in readline escapes like so:

```
echo -e "[\001\e[1;31m\002⎇ $BRANCH\001\e[1;37m\002]"
```

The readline escapes are `\001` at the start of a non-printing sequence, and `\002` at the end. These are equivalent to `\[` and `\]`, respectively, in the PS1 string.

Source: [archemiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43462720/4518341) on [bash prompt and echoing colors inside a function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6592077/4518341)